# Word spacing randomly gets large within certain paragraphs in Word

Tags: ms-word, documentation

Here is the problem I need help with. I can't seem to find a solution to this.
[image]

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word or on **Super User** https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or other forums. If you do post something there, you should delete this question or at least add a link in your question here to the new question there to help others.

Comment: @Charles, feel free to click on the _Close_ link below the post and add a reason to help speed the closing process. Thanks!

Comment: @JohnKorchok, I don't have enough points yet in SO to vote on close. I did flag it.